# How to have 2 columns in a subquery but ignore one of them?

Tags: database, postgresql, subquery, in-subquery

I'm trying to execute this query on my database which is querying 2 tables based on the results of a third table.

```
SELECT *
FROM   ads_user AS u
       INNER JOIN ads_medium AS m
               ON u.id = m.owner_id
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT medium_id,
                                  Count(*) AS count
                           FROM   ads_click
                           WHERE  time > '2017-01-01'
                           GROUP  BY medium_id
                           ORDER  BY count DESC
                           LIMIT  100);
```

As you can see I'm using two columns in my subquery which the `count` column is necessary for the whole query to work. Unfortunately PostgreSql throws the `subquery has too many columns` error.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the count as a selected column and add (*) to the order by. Thus:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ads_user AS u
       INNER JOIN ads_medium AS m
               ON u.id = m.owner_id
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT medium_id
                           FROM   ads_click
                           WHERE  time > '2017-01-01'
                           GROUP  BY medium_id
                           ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
                           LIMIT  100);
```

Postgres complained because your IN referred to two columns, whereas it should only be one.  It is perfectly OK to have the Count(*) in the order by.